# App for displaying 30s rolling average power

Tags: power, smartphone-mount

I use a power meter without a dedicated cycling computer like Garmin or Wahoo, I prefer to ride with my phone on the handlebars.

I found a couple of cycle computer apps which can be paired with the power sensor, displaying some power data during the ride: Ride With GPS, Wahoo Fitness. However, they only display the momentary power data, which is very "jumpy" from second to second (plus some other stats like max 20s power, or average/normalized power over the whole ride).

Is there an app that allows the user to configure a rolling window of 5/10/20/30 seconds over which to average the power data? It would be much more useful for pacing oneself or training with power zones.

EDIT: I've accepted the answer about IpBike, because based on the description of its features it fits the bill. However I'd be grateful for more answers specifically for iPhone apps, not only Android.

Comment: You might get more info at softwarerecs.stackexchange.com

Comment: Thanks for all answers, everyone! I forgot to mention I'm on the iPhone, so even though the Android apps look like precisely the solution I was asking for, I can't use them... Oh well, OSMand made it from Android to the iPhone so maybe Jepster or IpBike will, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IpBike](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?hl=en&id=com.iforpowell.android.ipbike) (which I use without sensors)  gives rolling average power if your power meter is ANT+ (or BLE I think). The [example](http://www.iforpowell.com/cms/index.php?page=ipbike) shows a 20s average, which  can be configured.

This is Android only, and free to try for long enough to get a feel for it (not expensive after that).

Comment: There are various averaging window sizes and a configurable one.  There is a fixed one at 30S as it is used to feed into the Normalised power algorithm

Comment: Thanks @Ifor - I didn't have my phone to hand to check. (Ifor wrote IpBike so he knows what he's talking about )

Comment: A limitation appears to be that it currently supports ANT+ sensors, but Bluetooth support is in beta testing. I don't think any mainstream phones can receive ANT+ transmissions natively, although you can get an ANT+ key (may be called a dongle, but I'm not sure if dongle is specific to laptops or desktops). Almost all current power meters can transmit over Bluetooth. I'm not sure how reliable IpBike's current BT support is, and I'd generally recommend a dedicated cycling computer.

Comment: @WeiwenNg IpBike's BT support was very good last time I tried it, but I've certainly managed to find sensors that fail (manufacturer recommended Wahoo's app - That didn't work either).  It looks like waterproof  phones from big manufacturers tend to support ANT+, but I've moved towards cheap waterproof phones that don't as I don't need ANT+ and they seem more robust.  I wouldn't fancy using a dongle as that means opening the port covers and risking rain getting in (it rains a lot where I am)

Comment: I think this does highlight one of the several advantages of a dedicated bike computer. I realize that some people might buy a power meter and get annoyed that they have to go and buy a GPS unit as well. It's worth not risking your phone getting damaged by a fall or by water, or risking the phone running out of battery.

Comment: @Weiwen I know I'm rare in preferring a phone, but I get a better screen and a very configurable interface for 1/3 the price by using a cheap waterproof phone. Battery life - once I've optimised the settings I can navigate on screen for 270km/17 hours and not all dedicated units will do that or charge on the go

Comment: Yes there should be full support for Bluetooth low energy type sensors.  If you have the choice with your phone ANT+ is the way to go as it's more reliable.

Could you tell me where the Beta comment was seen?  It was officially beta for a long time but Google have improved the quality of there BT driver stack so I did a full release with it some time back.

Comment: I think Ifor's last comment should have been @Weiwen given the mention of something saying "beta".

Comment: @Ifor perhaps I misread, but the description on the Google store page has this sentence: "Bluetooth low energy, Bluetooth Smart support is in beta testing with support for Heart Rate , Bike speed and cadence, running speed and cadence and Bike Power (but not 2 pedal BLE meters). "

Answer (score 3):

I'm not convinced you'll find an entirely satisfactory app, as most people who invest in a pricey power meter would tend to use a separate device such as this one

https://www8.garmin.com/manuals/webhelp/edge530/EN-US/GUID-53FC7978-187F-4E53-AA33-04853F86B05F.html

This app seems like it might have what you are looking for

https://www.jepster.nl/features.html

There don't seem to be too many users, but the app was recently updated (11 October) and the author seems to respond to feedback, so possibly if it's not quite what you want you might get improvements made!?

Comment: The Garmin link goes to what appears to be a generic page. I assume that page describes the fields available on all Garmin devices that can display power (i.e. all their current bike computers, although in the past the lowest end ones weren't compatible with power meters).

Comment: The page says 'Edge 530 Owners manual' . If you refer here comment from Wade et al https://www.dcrainmaker.com/2018/04/garmin-edge-130-in-depth-review.html, then lower end devices may be designed for 'training' with 'power meters' but specifically excluded certain features such as those cited by the OP